# How does memcached cache a list of objects

Tags: memcached

I wonder how memcached caches a list of objects internally? Does it serializes the object list and stick it in the cache, or it serializes each individual object, and stick them in keys but all sharing a common signature so they can be retrieved together later on?
Thanks,

David

Comment: https://github.com/memcached/memcached ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is up to the client library and both approaches could be implemented. It is probably more likely to be that the entire list is serialized and that is how things are done in the Spymemcached client.